# Both icons (white, black) in themes

Tags: jquery-mobile

Jquery mobile has themes. I want to use black icons with theme A and white icons with theme B - how to do it? I can't see proper option in themeroller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need ThemeRoller for this. All you need is to add class `ui-alt-icon` to buttons with `data-theme="a"` or to *parent* container.

Button with `data-theme="a"` and *black* icon:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-home ui-alt-icon">Home</a>
```

Button with `data-theme="b"` (`ui-btn-b`) and *white* icon (default):

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-home">Home</a>
```

---

#### Override SVG icon color:

jQM 1.4 uses SVG to draw icons instead of *png*. Those SVG are used with `:after` pseudo selector e.g. `.ui-icon-home:after { background-image: url(SVG data); }`.

To change color, copy SVG data of the icon you want to override and look for `fill%3D%22%23`. In the below example, the color is `FFF` (white), change that value to any *hex* color you want.

```
.ui-icon-home:after {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,...fill%3D%22%23FFF...');
}
```

Blue icon `0000FF`

```
.ui-icon-home:after {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,...fill%3D%22%230000FF...');
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/d932v/)**

Comment: It works but I have my own theme build in http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com and there is no option to change icon color.

Comment: @piernik because new icons are SVG. You need to change SVG icons then.

Comment: Then I shouldn't use themeroller?

Comment: @piernik there is no option in ThemeRoller. You can do it manually but it'll be a hectic job to change all SVG classes for all icons. Unless you want to override specific icons.

Comment: Wow - how You did it?